# Moving Sprite groups

Tags: python, pygame

I've been reading the Pygame [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) for Sprite Groups, on its section for sprites it says:

> The groups are designed for high efficiency in removing and adding
>   Sprites to them. They also allow cheap testing to see if a Sprite
>   already exists in a Group. A given Sprite can exist in any number of
>   groups. A game could use some groups to control object rendering, and
>   a completely separate set of groups to control interaction or player
>   **movement.** Instead of adding type attributes or bools to a derived
>   Sprite class, consider keeping the Sprites inside organized Groups.
>   This will allow for easier lookup later in the game.

My aim is to get movement on sprite groups, but I can't find any examples online. Is it possibly to move all or some individual sprites in a sprite group, If so how?

Answer (score 1):

To move all `Sprites` in a `Group`, just use a simple `for` loop:

```
for spr in my_sprites_that_shall_move:
    spr.rect.move_ip(d_x, d_y)
```

The `Group` class does not conatin any functionality to control the movement of its `Sprites`

Comment: Thats awesome, but what if you want to get an individual sprite from the group and move that only.

Comment: In most cases you wouldn't directly use `move_ip(dx, dy)`, but rather setup a `sprite.update()` function, which moves the sprites according to their velocity.

Comment: @Pro-grammer since you can iterate over a `Group`, you can take the `Sprite` you want the way you would access it if it where in any other collection (I hope this sentence makes sense). e.g. `first_sprite = next(my_sprite_group)` or `next(spr for spr in my_group if spr.some_flag)`.

Comment: @MarcusMøller true, but I hope it's clear that this is just an example to show that you can iterate over a `Group` to access the sprites. If you want to simply call `update()` on each sprite, you would just call `update()` on the group itself.

Comment: @DominicKexel Oh, the comment was merely directed at Pro-grammer. Wanted to inform him that if he did velocities (and changed them individually for each sprite), then he wouldn't have to worry about moving a single sprite as he could just call sprite.update() on all of them.